# https на некоторых страницах сайта. Настройка nginx

Tags: nginx

Нужно реализовать на сайте так чтобы https включался на некоторые части страницы, например /login.php и /my/. Но на всех других страницах чтобы перекидывал обратно на http.

Иными словами нужно сделать редирект с https на http для всех кроме /login.php и /my/.

Nginx настроен в связке с Apache

Comment: *Но на всех других страницах чтобы перекидывал обратно на http.* - зачем? Включите для всего сайта и всё.

Comment: @Etki, хотел написать такой же комментарий

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        ...
    }
    location = /login.php {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /my/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    location / {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location = /login.php {
        ...
    }
    location /my/ {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: там где у вас "...", у меня следующее 

proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size       10m;
client_body_buffer_size    128k;
proxy_connect_timeout      90;
proxy_send_timeout         90;
proxy_read_timeout         90;
proxy_buffer_size          4k;
proxy_buffers              4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
#proxy_intercept_errors on;

Comment: при переходе на /my/ или /login.php редиректит на главную

Comment: извиняюсь, почему то форматирование не сохраняется в комментариях

Comment: @15828, задай вопрос если ты ожидаешь от меня ещё какой-то комментарий

Comment: не могу разобраться, при переходе на /my/ или /login.php редиректит на главную /

Comment: вряд ли в этом виноват nginx. в ssl-ной части nginx в proxy_pass какая схема стоит?

Comment: в примере конфигурации я ошибочно написал директиву ssi, её нужно заменить на ssl. и, естественно, прописать туда сертификат и прочую атрибутику.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться